# .htaccess rewrite to index.php or index.html based on condition

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not so good with `htaccess` and tried to find an answer to my question but no luck so far.

So I have this `.htaccess` rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(api|nova|nova-api)
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Which works well.

The website is an Angular site where I have dynamic URLs which are routed by JS.

So if I open base domain: `example.com` works well because `index.html` is served.

But if I open a route like: `example.com/example-route`. It says 404.

Could you please help me how should I modify the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I don't understand, your Laravel Api and Angular project are in the same folder ?

Comment: Nope, it's separated. It's a legacy project which I took over from a dev team. They used nginx for rewrites but I had to migrate to apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(api|nova|nova-api)
> RewriteRule .* /index.php
> ```

You would seem to just need to rewrite the request to `index.html` *after* your API rewrite to `index.php`. However, you should modify your existing rule to add the `L` flag and the regex that matches the request should be anchored (although the *condition* is not required at all since the URL check should be performed in the `RewriteRule` directive itself).

For example, try the following instead:

```
# "index.html" needs to take priority when requesting the root directory
DirectoryIndex index.html

# Abort early if request is already "index.html" or "index.php"
RewriteRule ^index\.(html|php)$ - [L]

# Rewrite certain requests to Laravel API
RewriteRule ^(api|nova|nova-api)($|/) index.php [L]

# Rewrite everything else to Angular
# (unless it already maps to a file or directory)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Since the "homepage" is already working OK, it would suggest `DirectoryIndex` is already set OK in the server config (and prioritising `index.html`), although explicitly setting this to just `index.html` (as above) is more optimal, if this is all that's required.